# Classic Release pipeline trigger a build pipeline

Tags: azure-devops

I am using the classic pipeline. I have two pipelines: one for the DEV team to release our app to the App Service and one for the QA team to launch end-to-end tests. I would like to start the end-to-end test after our app is successfully deployed to App Service; What is the best way?

Currently, I added a new task to the release pipeline right after deploy was completed. The task is a PowerShell script which called Azure DevOps API to start a build pipeline. This approach worked. The only problem was I needed to provide my PAT for authentication. Is it possible to use OAuth access tokens like build pipeline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [System.AccessToken](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic#systemaccesstoken) in your REST API PowerShell script.

Steps:

1.Navigate to the job, under Additional options, check the Allow scripts to access the OAuth token box.
[image]

2.Add the following inline script in the PowerShell task to Queue a build.
[image]

```
$url = "$($env:SYSTEM_TEAMFOUNDATIONCOLLECTIONURI)$env:SYSTEM_TEAMPROJECTID/_apis/build/builds?api-version=5.1"

Write-Host "URL: $url"

$body = @"
{
    "definition": {
        "id": 51
    },
    "sourceBranch": "refs/heads/main",
    "sourceVersion": "",
    "reason": 1,
    "demands": [],
    "parameters": "{\"system.debug\":\"true\"}"
}
"@

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method POST -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $(System.AccessToken)"} -Body $Body -ContentType application/json
$response | ConvertTo-Json
```

3.Give the build service account the Queue builds permissions to build the pipeline. For more details you can refer [Manage build service account permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/access-tokens?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic#manage-build-service-account-permissions).

[image]

Otherwise you may get the error like this:

```
TF215106: Access denied. Project Collection Build Service (OrgName) needs Queue builds permissions for build pipeline 51 in team project ProjectName to perform the action. For more information, contact the Azure DevOps administrator.
```

By the way, I also found an extension named [Trigger Build Task](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=benjhuser.tfs-extensions-build-tasks) for your reference.